# How should I go about scraping the text in dd tags between specific dt tags on a page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text from the dd classes in between the dd tags (which are being used for to mark different dates). I tried a really hackey method but it didn't work consistenly enough

```
timeDiv = mezzrowSource.find_all("dd", class_="orange event-date")
eventDiv = mezzrowSource.find_all("dd", class_="event")
index = 0 
for time in timeDiv:
    returnValue[timeDiv[index].text] = eventDiv[index].text.strip()
    if "8" in timeDiv[index+3].text or "4:30" in timeDiv[index+3].text:
        break
    index += 1
```

Enumerating in that way resulted in too much text from otherorked most of the time but would sometimes extract events from other dates. Here source of the section in question is pasted below. Any ideas?

```
  <dt class="purple">Sun, September 30th, 2018</dt>

    <dd class="orange event-date">4:30 PM to 7:00 PM</dd>
    <dd class="event"><a href="/events/4094-mezzrow-classical-salon-with-david-oei"
                         class="event-title">Mezzrow Classical Salon with David Oei</a>


    </dd>

    <dd class="orange event-date">8:00 PM to 10:30 PM</dd>
    <dd class="event"><a href="/events/4144-luke-sellick-ron-blake-adam-birnbaum"
                         class="event-title">Luke Sellick, Ron Blake &amp; Adam Birnbaum</a>


    </dd>

    <dd class="orange event-date">11:00 PM to 1:00 AM</dd>
    <dd class="event"><a href="/events/4099-ryo-sasaki-friends-after-hours"
                         class="event-title">Ryo Sasaki &amp; Friends &quot;After-hours&quot;</a>


    </dd>


  <dt class="purple">Mon, October 1st, 2018</dt>

    <dd class="orange event-date">8:00 PM to 10:30 PM</dd>
    <dd class="event"><a href="/events/4137-greg-ruggiero-murray-wall-steve-little"
                         class="event-title">Greg Ruggiero, Murray Wall &amp; Steve Little</a>


    </dd>

    <dd class="orange event-date">11:00 PM to 1:00 AM</dd>
    <dd class="event"><a href="/events/4174-pasquale-grasso-after-hours"
                         class="event-title">Pasquale Grasso &quot;After-hours&quot;</a>


    </dd>
```

Expected output is a dictionary that looks like this: {'4:30 PM to 7:00 PM': 'Mezzrow Classical Salon with David Oei', '8:00 PM to 10:30 PM': 'Greg Ruggiero, Murray Wall & Steve Little', '11:00 PM to 1:00 AM': 'Pasquale Grasso "After-hours"'}

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Could you add your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can use zip():

```
mezzrowSource = BeautifulSoup(html , 'lxml')
timeDiv = [tag.get_text() for tag in mezzrowSource.find_all("dd", class_="orange event-date")]
eventDiv = [tag.get_text().strip() for tag in mezzrowSource.find_all("dd", class_="event")]
print(dict(zip(timeDiv, eventDiv)))
```

Outputs:

```
{'4:30 PM to 7:00 PM': 'Mezzrow Classical Salon with David Oei', '8:00 PM to 10:30 PM': 'Greg Ruggiero, Murray Wall & Steve Little', '11:00 PM to 1:00 AM': 'Pasquale Grasso "After-hours"'}
```

**Updated:**

The elements you want data from are all siblings i.e. there are no elements containing each set of data, which makes it harder to get the data grouped as you want. The only thing in your favor is the fact that the element with the date comes first then the time and then the title. The time and title can be repeated. So this method selects all the elements we want and iterates over them. In the first iteration it stores the date in a string and creates a list of tuples containing the times and titles. When it next finds a date it appends the date and the list of tuple to a dictionary. At the end of the iterations it appends the final date and list of tuples to the dictionary. It is a bit messy but that is due to the lack of structure in the HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pprint

url = 'https://www.mezzrow.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'lxml')
ds = soup.find_all(True, {'class': re.compile('purple|event|orange event_date')})
ret = {}
tmp = []
i = None
for d in ds:
    if d.attrs['class']==['purple']:
        if i is not None:
            ret[i] = tmp
            tmp = []
        i = (d.get_text())
    elif d.attrs['class']==['orange', 'event-date']:
        j =  d.get_text()
    elif d.attrs['class']==['event']:
        tmp.append ((j,d.get_text(strip=True)))
ret[i] = tmp
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)
pp.pprint(ret)
```

outputs:

```
{'Fri, October 12th, 2018': [('8:00 PM to 10:30 PM',
                              'Rossano Sportiello, Pasquale Grasso & Frank '
                              'Tate'),
                             ('11:00 PM to 2:00 AM',
                              'Ben Paterson "After-hours"')],
 'Fri, October 5th, 2018': [('8:00 PM to 10:30 PM',
                             'Vanessa Rubin, Brandon McCune, Kenny Davis & '
                             'Winard Harper'),
                            ('11:00 PM to 2:00 AM',
                             'Joe Davidian "After-hours"')],
 'Mon, October 1st, 2018': [('8:00 PM to 10:30 PM',
                             'Greg Ruggiero, Murray Wall & Steve Little'),
                            ('11:00 PM to 1:00 AM',
                             'Pasquale Grasso "After-hours"')],
....
```

Then select the date you want from the dict object.

Comment: Thank you! the only issue is I want it to be only for the specific <dt> date I specify. Any idea how I'd go about this?

Comment: Updated in response to comment.

Comment: This works perfectly. I really appreciate it. I'm a little confused about how you went about this. Would you mind explaining what this does a little bit! Either way thank you so much!

Comment: Updated in response to comment.